# .NET Core 2 application that runs as windows service can't set BasePath to executable location

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application that runs fine from a command line but when I add it as a Windows Service and run it the SetBasePath is using odd locations and not the location of where the executable is which is where I have an appsettings.json file I'm trying to load.

```
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                //.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
```

I tried Environment.CurrentDirectory which works from a command line but as a windows service that ends up being c:\Windows\System32

When using the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location I end up with a path in a temp folder.  If my executable is in C:\MyWindowServices\MyWindowsService.exe how do I use SetBasePath to the correct location of the executable so that I can load the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can put your app under `Program Files` and use

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "YouAppfolder")
```

inside the following code

```
//using System;
//using System.IO;

.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "YouAppfolder"))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
```

Note that depending on your OS, it could be `Program Files` or `Program Files(86)`

Comment: Yes, I considered this but the installer allows the user to install it in any path they want so this wouldn't work as I would not know where it was installed.  Seems like there should be a way to get the physical location of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer to this.  All other solutions presented here and when you Google about this returned a temp folder instead of the actual location of the exe file.

```
var executablePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```